# Escaping StackView after making 0 linebreak in label

Tags: autolayout, storyboard, uikit

I'm trying to add a label to StackView, but the text in label is too big to display it. So I'm setting lines to 0 and after that my StackView escapes. I've set top, leading and trailing constraints for main StackView. Does anybody know how to fix this problem ? [image]

[image]

It must be like this [image]
But when I'm changing linebreak to 0 it become like on 2 screenshot

Comment: line break -> word wrapping?

Comment: Yes, to show all the text in label

Comment: Can you add a screenshot for what is happening and what is required?

Comment: Sure, i've updated it in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used the version of XCode 9.1, which had this bug in it and did not test the application on the simulator. Upgrading to a newer version solved this problem.